Try Ubuntu black screen Dell 5530
I am trying to boot Ubuntu 16.0.4.1 into the live cd version on a Dell Latitude 5530. Grub loads, after selecting Try Ubuntu I get a black screen. I have tried to install with both cd and usb, also tried 'nomodeset' and adjusting the gfxpayload to alternate resolution sizes. Any help would be appreciated.

Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL and off-topic here ... please find a current version, like Ubuntu 24.04. Maybe your old version don't support the hardware you have.
